# Images in the middle on WP8,

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-8, stretch, stretching

Please, tell me, how can I place the image inside in the middle?
Stretch: Uniform to fill. 
I want to focus was on the middle of the picture

[image: Stretch: Uniform to fill]

Comment: Could you give some more information? The middle of what Grid? StackPanel?

Comment: @ErtayShashko [example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0ywd2703snkk50j/Screenshot%202014-05-24%2003.22.25.png)

Comment: In this case, some code is worth a thousand words...

Comment: So you want to crop the middle 20x20 section of the image, even if it is much larger/not square?

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you Try setting your Image control set Stretch =Fill

```
<Image height="20" width="20" Stretch="Fill"/>
```

Comment: Most of the times, this is a bad idea, especially if the source does not have the same aspect ratio as the image control.

Answer (score 0):

If the aspect ratio of the image you want to put inside an Image control is not 1:1 and you  set the aspect ratio of your Image control to 1:1 (e.g. Width="20" and Height="20" you will have a deformed image.

So, the best approach is, set the Width="20" but don't set the Height, let it calculate that automatically. Then, set Stretch="Uniform" (not uniform to fill). It should display the image correctly.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the image inside a Border and set the HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment attributes of your image to 'Center'.